# Firefox quirk: select the first letter when an image is on the same line

Tags: css, firefox, pseudo-element

Per [MDN's article on the `::first-letter` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter):

> The ::first-letter CSS pseudo-element selects the first letter of the first line of a block, **if it is not preceded by any other content (such as images or inline tables) on its line**.

*(emphasis mine)*

So, how does one select the first letter when there is an image on the line? This is a case that happens rather often, sometimes beyond my control.

The below exemplifies this behavior in FireFox. I realize it's intended, but how do I select the first letter anyway?

```css
img {
  float: right;
}
div p:first-of-type::first-letter {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png">This paragraph will not have the expected style, because of the inline image.</p>

  <p>This is a second paragraph.</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>This paragraph will have the expected style.</p>

  <p>This is a second paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I can see a larger initial on Safari. Perhaps it's a Microsoft-only limitation.

Comment: Works in Chrome 40 64bit, Windows

Comment: @Jongware: No, it works on IE as well. Firefox is the outlier here.

Comment: Odd, I tested something similar in Safari that didn't work, but I see my example does! It seems you're all quite right: FF is indeed an outlier. @BoltClock's answer below rings truest. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The catch here is that you've floated the image, which means the image is no longer in-flow and in particular it means the image is no longer in the first formatted line  — or any line box, for that matter. Therefore the statement that the image is still inline is incorrect.

Firefox has a particularly deviant (or broken, depending on how you want to look at it) implementation of `::first-letter`, mostly stemming from ambiguities in the CSS2 spec that were resolved later in CSS2.1 yet still aren't resolved in the browser. To cite another example, it's not unlikely that while writing your CSS, you've tried to apply it to `div::first-letter` only to find that [it simply doesn't work](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=214004), forcing you to have to explicitly select `div p:first-of-type::first-letter` instead.

```css
img {
  float: right;
}
div::first-letter {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png">This paragraph will not have the expected style, regardless of the image.</p>

  <p>This is a second paragraph.</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>This paragraph will not have the expected style either.</p>

  <p>This is a second paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

All that said, fortunately it is possible to work around the issue at hand in Firefox by simply moving the image out of the first `p` such that the image exists as the first child of the `div` instead:

```css
img {
  float: right;
}
div p:first-of-type::first-letter {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png">

  <p>This paragraph will have the expected style, because the image now exists outside of the paragraph and thus no longer interferes with the ::first-letter pseudo-element.</p>

  <p>This is a second paragraph.</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>This paragraph will have the expected style.</p>

  <p>This is a second paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, now it's all coming together... I'll see if I can exert the necessary control to get the image out of the paragraph - I don't always control the content when faced with this situation. Thanks!

Comment: Do you think I should modify the title of my question to make it FF-specific, as that is indeed the scope of the issue?

Comment: @Tohuw: That wouldn't be a bad idea. Someone else has already added the tag for you.